# set a condition for empty inputs

Tags: php

I am trying to set a condition whereby an error is echoed if not all fields are filled out. The code I have written seems to always output true.

What am I doing wrong?

```
if (empty($oldpassword)||empty($newpassword)||empty($repatnewpassword))
```

Answer (score 2):

You are checking for one of them, meaning, if one of the fields is empty, it will result `true`. Change it to **and**, so you get `true` only if **all** of the fields are empty:

```
if ( empty($oldpassword) && empty($newpassword) && empty($repatnewpassword) )
```

If you need to make sure, that all fields are filled out and you need to know witch one is not filled, do a bit longer code:

```
# check first if old password is filled
if ( $oldpassword )  {

    # now, if that works, check if new passwords are filled ( and match too )
    if ( $newpassword && ( $newpassword == $repatnewpassword) ) {

        // do whatever password checks here, now you know that oldpassword is
        // filled and newpassord is filled and matches repatnewpassword

    } else {
        // new password is not filled or passwords don't match
    }

} else {
    // old password is not filled out
}
```

Comment: that's what I want if any box is empty it should be true but at the moment if all inputs are filled it still comes true

Answer (score 0):

You code will return true if $oldpassword is empty while $newpassword is not. Change all ¦¦ to &&.